# MVC4 application and WCF : How to create custom authentication?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm playing with Visual Studio and i've created a MVC4 application project that contains a authentication part (the default one). 
In the other hand, i've a web service (WCF) liked to a database managed by SQL server that contains Users(login, password) table.
I'd like to change the "default" authentication with a one linked to the data that are provided by the web service.
So, to be clear : How to query a remote database to check login/pwd correctness ?

Just to give you ideas of what have been done :
AccountController :

```
 [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login or password not correct");
            return View(model);
        }
```

LoginModel :

```
public class LoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Login form :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
        </li>
    </ol>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
```

Could I adapt it or is there another way to do such a authentication ? Thanks !
EDIT -------------------

I've try to do that BUT i've an issue. Here is my "new version" of the Login function :

```
[HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
        {
            try
            {
                var context = new MyEntity(new Uri("http://localhost:12345/MyWCF.svc/"));
                var usr = from user in context.PERSON
                          where user.LOGIN == model.UserName && user.PASSWORD == model.Password
                          select user;
                List<PERSON> lpers = usr.ToList();
                int nbRes = lpers.Count();

                //if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
                if (ModelState.IsValid && nbRes ==1)
                {
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                }
            }
            catch (DataServiceQueryException ex)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Erreur : "+ex.ToString());
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wrong username or pwd");
            return View(model);
        }
```

But i've got the following error :

```
System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQueryException: Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de cette requête. ---> System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?><error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><code></code><message xml:lang="fr-FR">Une erreur s'est produite lors du traitement de cette requête.</message></error> 
à System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery(DataServiceContext context) 
à System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents) 
--- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne --- 
à System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute[TElement](DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents) 
à System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute() 
à System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator() 
à System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) 
à System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) 
à MyApp.Controllers.AccountController.Login(LoginModel model, String returnUrl) dans d:\....\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MyProg\MyWS\Controllers\AccountController.cs:ligne 45
```

Where ligne 45 is

```
List<SteelcaseWebPortal.SteelcaseService.PERSON> lpers = usr.ToList();
```

Did I do something wrong with the request ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The easier way would be to change the below method to a custom one that will do the call to the web service.

```
WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe)
```

new one that returns a boolean :

```
MyWebService.Login(model.UserName, model.Password)
```

if then you want to persist the authentication in a cookie level. Add the following when the if passes:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);
```